# Netbeans 7.2 autocomplete for namespace class

Tags: php, netbeans, code-hinting

**Edit:** Bug reported, accepted and patched http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=225062

Since a day or two my Netbeans IDE stopped hinting class arguments and autocompletion does not work for namespaced classes, and I'm simply wondering what I might have done to break the autocompletion/hinting - or if this is a known bug. This reproduces on Ubuntu 12.10 and Windows 7 using Netbeans 7.2 and also with Netbeans 7.3 beta 2.

This would be strange if it is a known bug because I'm almost certain it was working a couple of days ago.

Scenario;
Class *HostNameRoute* exists within the *Router\Route* namespace, the constructor takes two arguments *$route* and *$action*.

```
namespace Router\Route;
class HostNameRoute {}
```

From the root namespace I used to be able to get hints and autocomplete by typing:

```
new HostNam[Ctrl+Space]  ::  Suggests HostNameRoute($route, $action)  :: [Enter]

Would produce
new \Router\Route\HostNameRoute(<$route>, <$action>);
```

But now the IDE just hints the qualified name but does not show argument documentation nor does it autocomplete. It does however spawn a static strange box over the class name (not interactive).

However, the hinting and autocompletion still works for classes in the root namespace:

```
new Te[Ctrl+Space]  :: Suggests Test($arg) :: [Enter]

Produces
new Test(<$arg>);
```

---

**Works for root namespace**
[image: Autocomplete works]

---

**Does not work for namespaced class**
[image: No autocomplete]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had a similar issue where Netbeans stopped autocompleting within a specific project (other projects were working fine). I am running Netbeans 7.2.1 on Windows 7. I am also using namespaces and use statements. When trying to use autocomplete, Netbeans was just giving me variable names declared in the same method. Using the *this* keyword within a class wouldn't even give me variables/methods in that class.

Here is what I did to fix it:

1. Went to the "Project" window and right clicked on my project and hit close
2. Closed Netbeans
3. Deleted Netbeans' cache. This can be found at C:\Users\ProfileName\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\7.2.1 on a Windows machine.
4. Opened Netbeans
5. Added my code back as a project by going to File->New Project...
6. Checked autocomplete and it worked!

Comment: This actually helped med today since the autocomplete stopped working in whole for one of my projects. Though my original question was actually a bug in netbeans; http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=225062

Comment: On Linux the path is ~\.cache\netbeans\<version>

Comment: Amazing, 2 hours wasted on this never should happen issue, thanks