# PHP namespace code completion in netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans, composer-php, php-7, netbeans-8.2

I have a PHP project in NetBeans 8.2 and I was able to use the code completion to find NameSpaces in my composer vendor folder to add to my use statements. However, I opened the project today, and I am not able to do find any of those packages with code completion. Other projects are able to use this feature. I have a feeling I am over looking a project setting, but I haven't changed any of those recently.

I am using composer to require and autoload using PSR-4.

I have tried to clear my cache as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14419942/2264016), but this did not fix my issue.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I used to use netbeans and there were several times I had to reinstall the program after some config file went corrupt.  I recommend switching to something else or reinstalling.

Comment: I have reinstalled, and that did not fix the issue. Do you have a recommendation of what program to switch to? Sublime 3, and PHPStorm are not a good option for me.

Comment: @JamesRay phpstorm is really great IDE where as sublime is a really good editor, so you should definitely go with phpstorm.

Comment: Again Phpstorm is not an option. Number one reason due to licencing.